existence of a minimal prime ideals containing some ideal zorn's lemma
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{A}$ an ideal in $R$ contained in a prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$. Prove that there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$ satisfying $\mathfrak{A} \subset \mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{P}$ and with $\mathfrak{p}$ minimal among all prime ideals containing $\mathfrak{A}$.
I'm supposed to use Zorn's lemma in some way. I thought maybe the following would work: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all prime ideals containing $\mathfrak{A}$. Clearly $\mathcal{P}$ is nonempty since $\mathfrak{P} \in \mathcal{P}$. Now consider $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{P}} \mathfrak{p}$. I'm not sure I can show that this intersection is a prime ideal though.

You can't. But what you can show is that if you take any chain in $\mathcal{P}$ then the intersection of the elements of the chain will indeed be a prime ideal. And that is what you need to apply Zorn's lemma.

The intersection of prime ideals is not generally a prime ideal. $(2)\cap(3)=(6)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
